# NodeJS XML HTTP POST request headers object not accepting

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, request, http-post

I am trying to get a Ping message back from an API of a channel manager for hotels. (XML Open Travel Alliance)

I made the HTTP XML POST request first with SoapUI-5.3.0 tool including the following parameter:

```html
otaRQ: <OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="3.30" TimeStamp="2011-07-24T10:07:24" Target="Production"> <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]> </EchoData> </OTA_PingRQ>
```

and received the following XML response:

```html
<OTA_PingRS PrimaryLangID="en" Target="Production" TimeStamp="2017-03-21T09:43:55" Version="3.00" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
   <Success/>
   <EchoData>Hello World!!</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
```

I included the same parameter in the http POST request in NodeJS in the options variable in the headers object. (see code below)

Still I recieve the following response: 200 "'otaRQ' is missing in post-form data!"

So my question is, how do I get the same response like with SoapUI-5.3.0?

Thanks a lot for the efforts!

```js
var http = require('http');

var body = '<OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="3.30" TimeStamp="2011-07-24T10:07:24" Target="Production"> <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]></EchoData> </OTA_PingRQ>'

var postRequest = {
    hostname: "cultswitch.cultuzz.de",
    path: "/cultswitch/processOTA",
    method: "POST",
    port: 8080,
    headers: {
        'otaRQ': '<OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="3.30" TimeStamp="2011-07-24T10:07:24" Target="Production"> <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]> </EchoData> </OTA_PingRQ>',
        'Cookie': "cookie",
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
};

var buffer = "";

var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res )    {

console.log( res.statusCode );
var buffer = "";
res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; } );
res.on( "end", function( data ) { console.log( buffer ); } );

});

req.on('error', function(e) {
console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write( body );
req.end();
```

Excerpt from channel manager provider: 
The data exchange will be carried out using the standard HTTP protocol. The
request message should be sent as POST-DATA within a parameter called 'otaRQ'
and the reply message will be written directly into the HTTP-Response by the
CultSwitch. CultSwitch accepts request in "text/xml" format only. CultSwitch also
supports gzip compression for every request and response. The requesting system
should set proper request headers. "PrimaryLangID" is mandatory to post any
request to CultSwitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that it requires your parameter be called otaRQ. You have not done that. Try this:

```
var body = 'otaRQ=<OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="3.30" TimeStamp="2011-07-24T10:07:24" Target="Production"> <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]></EchoData> </OTA_PingRQ>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your error message says that you are missing post-form data, try setting your content-type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

So, 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it is not working either (same response) @gjegadesh